# Using Unity to call a static injection method

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

We have a class (in fact many) that have a static initialization function that it needs to carry out on an object within the dependency injection container (using Unity).

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void InitializeMappings(IMapper mapper)
    {
        // Do stuff to mapper
    }
}
```

I would like the `InitializeMappings` function to be called whenever a new IMapper instance is instantiated by the Unity container.

I need help to:

- Call the `InitializeMappings` function from the container
- Resolve the `mapper` parameter for the function call
- Connect up the call to `InitializeMappings` to the lifetime of IMapper implementations

How would I go about implementing/defining this?

Comment: It's a static method. You can easily call it yourself once during app startup.

Comment: @Steven - But then how do I bind the static function to the lifetime of the container item (that is, the IMapper)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is bad design; why not have the mapper implementations call the setup function in their constructors directly?

You can get the container to do this, either through an extension, or by using an injection factory. Something like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IMapper>(
    new WhateverLifetimeYouWant(),
    new InjectionFactory(
        c => {
            var mapper = c.Resolve<IMapper>("RealMapper");
            MyClass.InitializeMappings(mapper);
            return mapper;
        }
)
.RegisterType<IMapper, ActualMapper>("RealMapper");
```

Then whenever you do `container.Resolve<IMapper>()` it'll run that little chunk of code.

This only works through the API, not through config files.

Comment: My mapper implementation was a class I didn't have access to. However, in hindsight I should have wrapped it up and done as you suggest at the top - by calling them in the constructor. But this approach only holds in the case where the number of mapper implementations is controlled.

The injection factory idea worked great though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In WPF I believe you can do the following

```
container.RegisterType<Mapper, Mapper>();
container.Register<IMapper>(
    new InjectionFactory(c => {
        var mapper = c.Resolve<Mapper>(); 
        MyClass.InitializeMappings(mapper);
        return mapper;
    })
);
```

As far as "Connect up the call to the lifetime of the IMapper" I don't get what you mean. Any objects created and only referenced by the mapper object would be garbage collected when the mapper object was.